# removing ipod from supported devices

Tags: ios, app-store-connect, ipod, info.plist

I've read that I can do that by setting `magnetometer` key in the UIRequiredDeviceCapabilities in the info.plist file. I am however unsure if I must **replace** value `armv7` or leave that value and **add** a new value called `magnetometer` as the second entry in  UIRequiredDeviceCapabilities. I added a screenshot of what I looks now. Please inform me if it is set correctly[image]

EDIT: 3GS devices should not be supported

EDIT: ended up with this. not sure if it is correct. I expect iPad1, 3gs, ipods to be excluded.[image]

EDIT:

This is how it looks in itunes connect. I still don't know if I excluded ipods, because the device family is `iPhone / iPod touch, iPad`.
[image]

Comment: You can exclude non-phone devices by requiring the telephony capability

Comment: yes, but this doesnt help me include ipads

Comment: Why do you need to exclude ipods if they are capable of running the app?

Comment: Firstly, I have none to test. Secondly, I expect poor performance for all expect the latest 1 or 2

Comment: Then if apple does not provide a way to exclude only ipods, maybe you should let the user decide if the app works well on his device.

Comment: valid point. I believe front-facing-camera adds adittional restriction to exclude all ipods, 3gs phones and ipad 1 as a collateral damage but I can live with that.